# How to create/register multiple instances of view/vewmodel in a ListView binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

Writing a C# wpf application using mvvm with prism and unity, I cant find an answer how to solve a situation that should be common imho:

*Displaying multiple Views in a ListView with (xaml) binding.*

Having a View/ViewModel named `MainTableItemsControl`/`MainTableItemsControlViewModel` with a collection in the view model:

`public WpfObservableRangeCollection<base_main> BaseData { get; set; }`

What I want to do is:
display each of the objects in the BaseData Collection **not** with hard coded xaml **but** with a view (including viewmodel).

### The question:

*How **should** it be done?* (the MVVM way with prism and unity preferrably)

(How to create individual instances of view/view model pairs for each object in the collection and use them with binding in xaml)

Maybe there is a completely different approach needed? After hours and hours of testing and investigating I cannot find a single example facing that scenario.

So far I used a workaround. I was ok with that because it worked ...until I was facing new issues not allowing me to procceed (I cannot get/pass the region manager for instance to further define the view/viewmodel for each instance).

### My not satisfying workaround (not the should do MVVM way):

each `base_main` object (in the Model) creates its own View Model as its beeing constructed:

```
public class base_main :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ViewModels.SingleArticleItemViewModel single_vm { get; set; }
  public base_main()
  {
     single_vm = new ViewModels.SingleArticleItemViewModel(this);
  }
//(...)
}
```

a collection is referenced in the `MainTableItemsControlViewModel`

```
public class MainTableItemsControlViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public MainTableItemsControlViewModel(IRegionManager RegionManager, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _regionManager = RegionManager;
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

            BaseDataCollection = Model.MySingletonBaseDataCollection;

            BaseDataViews = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(BaseDataCollection);
        }
}
```

and that collection is used in the `MainTableItemsControl` to create a list of the views of type `SingleArticleItem` (binding the collection: `ItemsSource="{Binding BaseDataViews}"` and providing the data context: `DataContext="{Binding Path=single_vm}"`)

```
<ListView VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding BaseDataViews}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type views:SingleArticleItem}">
                    <views:SingleArticleItem DataContext="{Binding Path=single_vm}" Margin="0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            //(...)
</ListView>
```

This way I construct a View/ViewModel pair for each `base_main` object setting the data context to wire up the ViewModel directly (SingleArticleItem xaml is not auto wireing: `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="False"`)

Even though it is "working", its not the mvvm ways at all and has its limitations as further work arounds have their limitations. Eg.
in the resulting `SingleArticleItem` instances I am not able to get the RegionManager in time (not at instanciation). For the event aggregator this is called on any property change event

```
if (_eventAggregator == null && ServiceLocator.IsLocationProviderSet)
  {
    _eventAggregator = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>();
   InformUpdateCommand = new DelegateCommand(InformUpdate);
 }
```

Comment: Add view models of multiple types to the source collection and use implicit data templates in the view?

Comment: view models of multiple types? you mean one for each `base_main` object? if so: thats not an option, because there are thousands of these objects and they are created at runtime. Maybe there is an idea registering named view/viewmodels in the unity container on object creation time and resolve them (somehow) in xaml with binding the names (somehow???)?

Answer (score 0):

> each base_main object (in the Model) creates its own View Model as its beeing constructed:
>
> ```
> public class base_main : INotifyPropertyChanged
> {
>     public ViewModels.SingleArticleItemViewModel single_vm { get; set; }
>     public base_main()
>     {
>         single_vm = new ViewModels.SingleArticleItemViewModel(this);
>     }
> }
> ```

That's the wrong way, do it the other way round. Not the model creates the view model, but the view model contains a reference to the model. The view model is created for one or more models of one or more types, there's not even neccessarily a one-to-one relation.

So take you collection of models and create a collection of view models from them in the view model that wants to show the collection. Also, add code to synchronize the two collections, in case the user can create new models or new models come in from the original source of the models. Hint: only do full two-way synchronization if you can't help it, because it will be a lot of code and a lot more tests...

Comment: thanks a lot for the response. I know that its not the supposed way I do it ;-). But you are pointing out exactly whats the downside of this approach: creating another collection that needs to be synchronized. Maybe the idea could be: register a named (unique id)  view/viewmodel in `base_main` object creation by using the unity container and _somehow_ receive the views via binding the unique id..? (but I have no idea how that could work)

Comment: Having two collections, one for the models and one for the view models, is the only clean way. Chances are, you do not have to account for all possible synchronization modes, so it may be quite simple. Even full synchronization is more understandable than mixing up models and view models, I suppose, as it is essentially an implementation detail of your `SynchronizedCollectionOfViewModels`...